Analytical TOV Solution For Certain EoS Models
I saw a post earlier about how we can solve the TOV equation analytically for the ideal case of constant pressure EoS, but I wanted to know if I can solve it for the case where:
$P(E) = kE + P_0$, where $E$ is energy density and $P$ is pressure. I'm not sure how to go about this and how I can determine if my resulting system has a closed form solution. Does anyone have any idea about how to go about this?

Consider to spell out acronyms.
